# Rails : methodology log in in front and admin section

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build an admin section in my rails application.
I am quite to new rails and I have some difficulties about the methodology.

So the routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                  'static_pages#home'
  get     'help'    =>  'static_pages#help'
  get     'about'   =>  'static_pages#about'
  get     'contact' =>  'static_pages#contact'
  get     'signup'  =>  'users#new'
  get     'login'   =>  'sessions#new'
  post    'login'   =>  'sessions#create'
  delete  'logout'  =>  'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users, except: [:index]

  # namespace :admin do
  #   root  'base#home'
  #   get   'login'       =>  'sessions#home'
  #   post  'login'       =>  'admin/sessions#create'
  #   get   'dashboard'   =>  'base#dashboard'
  #   resources :users
  # end

  namespace :admin do
    root  'base#home'
  end

end
```

There is a model User avalaible in the front.
So users can login via a login from

```
views/sessions/new.html.erb

<div id="login_form">
  <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and edit their profile with the SessionController

```
app/controllers/sessions_controller

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def new
      end

      def create
        @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
          log_in @user
          params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
          redirect_to @user
          remember @user
        else
          flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def destroy
        log_out if logged_in?
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

And a base controller app/controllers/admin/base_controller.rb

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController

  layout 'admin'

  before_action :logged_in_user

  def home
  end

  private
    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        (redirect_to login_url)
      end
    end
end
```

That's where I am confused because in case of a non-admin user, he's redirected to his profile page (it works fine) but the admin user should be redirected to the admin home page.

I tried to have two different login forms but I had an infinite loop redirection because I was redirecting to the login page in case of non logged in but

```
before_action :require_login
```

was called for every action event the login page

What would be the right methodology ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your admin users log in the same way a regular user would: via `SessionsController#create`. It also seems like you have a second controller `SessionsController` in the `Admin` namespace, which is not used?

> That's where I am confused because in case of a non-admin user, he's redirected to his profile page (it works fine) but the admin user should be redirected to the admin home page.

You currently don't differentiate between the "normal" user and an admin, therefore both are `redirect_to @user`. (the users profile page).

> What would be the right methodology?

You could add field to your user model (`boolean admin`) which you could use to differentiate in your `SessionsController`.

```
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in @user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
      if @user.admin?
        redirect_to 'admin_home_page'
      else
        redirect_to @user
      end
      remember @user
```

That way you don't need a second `SessionsController`. Furthermore
you could write an admin "filter" in your controllers which would only allow access to certain controller actions if the `@user` is an admin.

```
class Controller
    before_filter :admin_only
    private
      def admin_only
        redirect_to :back, unless @user.admin?
      end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am gonna do this. So the way you show me is a good practice in this situation ?

Comment: I'm not sure what is considered best/good practice. There are many solutions including libraries, like [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/). But since you're learning I think it is good if you build this yourself.